# What test for a 4-level categorical variable and a continuous variable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, categorical-data, continuous-data

I'm currently doing research on whether image quality affects engagement. Image quality is given in 4 categories (bad, benchmark, semi-professional and commercial level) and engagement is in how many views it attracts.

The hypothesis is that image quality affects engagement, so we are hypothesis testing.

My teacher said chi-square but I know that needs two categorical variables.

Comment: Where is the continuous variable exactly?

Comment: so the engagement, counted in views, is continuous.

Comment: No.  Those are counts.  You can't have 54.543 views can you?  Chi-squared sounds like a good choice.

Comment: Okay great! Maybe it's simply my spss skill that are lacking haha

Comment: No problem, although this doesn't really have much to do with SPSS, but with how to define variables. We're always happy to help others understand their data.

Comment: @StatsStudent Engagement certainly could be considered a continuous variable when the view counts are all "large."  The meaning of "large" could be as small as 10, depending on the circumstances.  Because a chi-squared analysis does not account for the ordinal nature of the categories, it's not a preferable choice (although it could discern whether there is *some* relationship with image quality, that's all it could do).

Comment: "Image quality affects engagement" isn't much of an hypothesis.  Have you considered *exploring* (at least part of) your data in order to develop a specific hypothesis and then testing that hypothesis with separate data?

Comment: That's a fair point & I agree, but I think it's just natural to consider these as counts, especially if one is considering treating the variable as continuous & then performing something like a a standard regression analysis since that could pose problems since the counts are be bounded by zero (again, as you pointed out this is less of a problem with larger numbers). BTW, I think the OP should take serious note about your hypothesis (or lack thereof) comment & develop that a bit more. Only once a serious hypothesis is developed & data examined, can one really understand how to treat the data.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, engagement is a count variable. What sorts of values does it get?  If it gets a lot of different values over a wide range, then it may be fine to do linear regression.  If it gets fewer different values, or if they are all relatively low, then you may want a count regression model such as Poisson or negative binomial regression.

I don't see how chi-square could be right, but if you decide (for some reason) to treat engagement as an ordinal variable, then some method that uses that info could be good. I like the Jonckheere Terpstra test for that sort of thing.

From your comment, the range is quite broad so you could probably start with linear regression but carefully examine the assumption and deal with those that are violated. In particular, as @whuber points out, heteroscedasiticity is likely to be a problem.

Quantile regression does not assume homoscedasticity, so that might work better.

Comment: My data simply has the four categories of image quality and then a frequency count for the views.

Comment: I do have three different images for which I count this, could those be classified as three different categories?

Comment: You didn't answer my question about the range of counts

Comment: the range is between 30-124.

Comment: "Linear regression," if applied, really needs to account for the (obvious and quantifiable) heteroscedasticity of the responses, at a minimum.  But how would the ordinal nature of the regressor be handled?

Comment: @whuber I just suggested it as a start. If the assumptions were violated (and I am not sure why heteroscedasticity is "obvious") they could be dealt with in the usual ways. Ordinal regressors are a problem. I kind of like optimal scaling, but that's a bit esoteric.

Comment: The heteroscedasticity is obvious because the variance of a count response is proportional to the count; the counts vary by more than a factor of four; and that factor should be enough to make one concerned about it.